# Dynamic Bayesian Network library in Python

Tags: bayesian, python, graphical-model, bayesian-network

Can you please introduce me a good python library that supports both learning (structure and parameter) and inference in Dynamic Bayesian Network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, I see we're working on a similar topic at the same time https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307577/inference-for-dynamic-bayesian-networks?rq=1  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307747/possible-limitations-of-dynamic-bayesian-networks-and-valid-alternatives if you would be interested in talking about this topic, I will create a chat room on this site and provide you the link so that you can join. If you are not interested, I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Done! Here's the link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67222/dynamic-bayesian-networks PS when in the chat, you can write `@DeltaIV` to ping me.

Comment: Hmm maybe I made a mistake, try this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67226/dynamic-bayesian-networks

Answer (score 7):

Try [pgmpy](http://pgmpy.org/models.html).

You can also create something on your own by using more generic tools for Graphical Probabilistic Models such as [PyJaggs](https://pyjags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Edward](http://edwardlib.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if pgmpy inference in DBN or not

Comment: I checked it. Elimination Ordering is supported. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just found pomegranate. Does it help? https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html